# Python rewriting data text file grades program

Tags: python, function, text-files

Searching for help with a program. The task is to rewrite the program from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175692/python-data-text-file-grades-program).
The directions are to create a function called `def username(first, last):`. The function `username` will have two parameters, `first` and `last`. The output will be the same as the original text file grade program.

This is what I have so far:

```
def username(first, last):

    for lines in aList:
        n = lines.split()
        first = n[0][0].lower()
        last = n[1][0:4].lower()
        resultName = first + last + "001"

    return resultName

def main():

    inFile = open("grades.txt", "r")
    aList = inFile.readlines()

    print(username)

    inFile.close

main()
```

the output I'm receiving:

```
function username at 0x7f68f83a5158
```

the output I should be receiving:

```
>>>username('Jane', 'Smith')

jsmit001
```

Any insight on what I can do to make this program run correctly would be appreciated.

I played around with this program and found that:

```
def username(first, last):

    inFile = open("grades.txt", "r")
    aList = inFile.readlines()

    for lines in aList:
        n = lines.split()
        first = n[0][0].lower()
        last = n[1][0:4].lower()
        resultName = first + last + "001"

        return resultName

    infile.close

def main():

    print(username(first = "Jane", last = "Smith"))


main()
```

it works now, but gives me only the first line from my text file. The output is correct, but I need all 5 usernames. I believe it is an indentation problem somewhere but I am unsure where it is. By un-indenting "return resultName" once my output was the last line in my text file.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, one function doesn't use its parameters (and will cause a `NameError` as you haven't defined the one it needs) and the other prints a function, rather than calling it and printing the results.

Comment: Why doesn't that function use its parameters?  @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you mean *"why"*? I don't know why; that's the way you wrote it. `username`tries to assign the contents of `aList` (`NameError`) to `first` and `last` before doing anything with them, thus replacing the values you passed in.

Comment: You need to re-read the specification; the new version of `username` **still doesn't use its arguments**, and does work that's supposed to be done in `main`.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question - if you've cracked it, add you own answer (note that future users would find it more useful if you included an explanation of what was wrong originally and what exactly you changed and why to fix it).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website and programming as you can see. Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(username)
```

Here you miss the arguments (first,last). At the moment you just ask where the function is saved, so where the pointer is set to

Answer (score 0):

An issue with your program.

1. You have not called the username function. So when you do 
   print(username)
   the output that you get is the address where the function is stored.

Hope it helps.

```
def username(first, last):
  for lines in aList:
    n = lines.split()
    first = n[0][0].lower()
    last = n[1][0:4].lower()
    resultName = first + last + "001"

 return resultName

def main():

  inFile = open("grades.txt", "r")
  aList = inFile.readlines()
  #first  == aList[0]
  #last = aList[1] #Something like this I expect
  print(username) ##Pass the values to the function which will return you the value "resultName" which you want to print 

  inFile.close()

main()
```